# Dropzonejs - Doesn't show progress bar / complete status and doesnt hide fallback form

Tags: python, django, dropzone.js

I'm using latest dropzone.js, version 3.2.0. I downloaded the folder and have all files needed. Using latest Chrome.

When i drop a file, dropzone sends it to the server, and i successfully save it, but nothing visual happens on the front end.

I guess i'm missing something trivial. How to make dropzone show upload progress animation?

Another issue i have is that dropzone doesnt hide the `div.fallback` that contains fallback form.

I thought those features supposed to work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds as if you didn't include the CSS files that come along with Dropzone.

Or you didn't add the `dropzone` or `dropzone-previews` class to your form.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('.dz-fallback').hide();
```

use .hide() instead of .remove() method. Because .remove() will remove that div permanent.